# How to trigger a js function with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger this jquery function by using trigger method of JQuery. How can I do that ? Actually I dont even know the trigger method is suitable for user defined functions.

```
$('a.pop').click(function() {alert('testing'); }
```

**this is not working**

```
 $('a').trigger(testtt);

 var testtt = function(){ alert('aaa');}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very similar to the way you install the event handler:

```
$('a.pop').click();
```

If you have the name of the event you want to trigger as a string, you can also do it this way:

```
$('a.pop').trigger('click');
```

This is also the solution to use if you want to pass crafted data to the event handler -- [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) also accepts a second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger a click event on the element by simply running

```
$('a.pop').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('a.pop').click()`, or if you're triggering some dynamic method, or custom event:

`$('a.pop').trigger(eventName)`, e.g: `$('a.pop').trigger('click');`

Answer (score 0):

Reading from jQuery API, the following should work.

```
$('a.pop').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

[`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) is used to trigger event handlers (custom or built-in').  Since you bound your function to the "click" handler, you can use `trigger` like so to call it:

```
$('a.pop').trigger('click');
```

jQuery's event binding methods can also be called without parameters to trigger them, which means you can also do this:

```
$('a.pop').click();
```